# Powershell command for IIS 7 for replacing one string with another

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I have a configuration setting in web. config file as follows:

```xml
<param name="url" value="http://localhost/services.msc">
```

I want to write a batch file using powershell to replace value="http://localhost/services.msc"
with port number as value="http://localhost:808/services.msc"

Is it possible to replace one text with another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  My favorite way to modify any XML file if I know the value I'm trying to modify is to cast the content as XML, find the setting right where I know it to be, to modify it, and then to set the content of the config file to what I now have in powershell.  An example is below.  To find the exact value I usually take the item above it and pipe it to | fl until I get exactly what I'm looking at.  You can read the XML and get the info probably alot easier.

```
#Make sure you set the webconfigpath variable.  
#Make sure you know your keyname and where to find it in the XML doc.
$webConfig = [xml](Get-Content -path $webConfigPath)
$setting = $webConfig.configuration.appSettings.add | ?{$_.key -eq "KeyName"}
$setting.Value = "NewValue"
$webConfig.save($webConfigPath)
```

This may be something that can be changed with the Set-WebConfigurationProperty cmdlet, but I'm not sure and haven't used it personally.